# Binary Search Tree segmentation fault

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am making a binary search tree for a movie rental business (theoretically). I need to output "Movie not found" if a title that the movie rental business doesn't have is typed in. I'm not sure how to do this without getting a segmentation fault every single time. I'm not sure what else to try-to me this code makes sense. I'm only a beginner- please go easy on me. Any help would be greatly appreciated! (You can find my if function that attempts to output "Movie not found" in between the three slashes (///) towards the end of my code.

```
void MovieTree::rentMovie(std::string title)
{ 
     MovieNode *foundMovie = root; 
     //MovieNode *parent = NULL; 
if (root == NULL) 
{ 
    cout << "Movie not found." << endl;
    return; 
}
else 
{ 
    foundMovie = root; 
    while (foundMovie != NULL) 
    { 
        if (foundMovie == NULL) //tree is empty 
        { 
            cout << "Movie not found." << endl; 
        } 

        else 
        { 
            if (foundMovie->title.compare(title) > 0) //uses ASCII to determine where titles are 
            { 
                foundMovie->parent = foundMovie; 
                foundMovie = foundMovie ->leftChild; 
                //cout << "printed left" << endl; //debugging
                if (foundMovie->title.compare(title) == 0 && foundMovie->quantity > 0) 
                { 
                    foundMovie->quantity--;
                    cout << "Movie has been rented." << endl;
                    //Title entered matches title found 
                    cout << "Movie Info:" << endl;
                    cout << "===========" << endl; 
                    cout << "Ranking:" << foundMovie->ranking << endl; 
                    cout << "Title:" << foundMovie->title << endl; 
                    cout << "Year:" << foundMovie->year << endl; 
                    cout << "Quantity:" << foundMovie->quantity << endl;
                    break;
                }

                else if (foundMovie->quantity ==0)
                {
                    //If movie is out of stock 
                    cout << "Movie out of stock." << endl; 
                    break;
                }
            } 
            else //check rightChild 
            { 
                foundMovie->parent = foundMovie; 
                foundMovie = foundMovie->rightChild; 
                //cout << "printed right" << endl; //debugging
                if (foundMovie->title.compare(title) == 0 && foundMovie->quantity > 0) //title entered matches title found 
                { 
                    foundMovie->quantity--;
                    cout << "Movie has been rented." << endl;
                    cout << "Movie Info:" << endl;
                    cout << "===========" << endl; 
                    cout << "Ranking:" << foundMovie->ranking << endl; 
                    cout << "Title:" << foundMovie->title << endl; 
                    cout << "Year:" << foundMovie->year << endl; 
                    cout << "Quantity:" << foundMovie->quantity << endl;
                    break;
                }
                else if (foundMovie->quantity ==0) 
                { 
                    //movie is found but out of stock 
                    cout << "Movie out of stock." << endl;
                    break; 
                } 
            }
        }
    }
    ///
    if (foundMovie->title == title) 
    {
        cout << "found the movie" << endl; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        cout << "Movie not found." << endl; 
    }
    ///
}
```

}

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `foundMovie->parent = foundMovie;` is not a good idea; it creates a circular dependency.

Comment: Another recommendation: Separate the movie logic from the tree logic. This allows you to separately test the tree and the movie and easily determine which is at fault. Testing both at the same time puts you in a nasty place where you may actually fix a bug in one and not realize it because of a bug in the other.

Comment: Since you indicated you are a beginner, here's a walk-through of refactoring your code: http://pastebin.com/4tP5VzKK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some remarks/bugs in your code

- You can remove no more useful conditions: it reduces the readability of your code.

  ```
  while (foundMovie != NULL) 
  { 
      if (foundMovie == NULL) // false by construction!!!
      ...
  }
  ```
- `foundMovie->parent = foundMovie;` should disappear. It creates a circular dependency !
- Your last statement `if (foundMovie->title == title)` can create a segmentation fault since
  `foundMovie` can be NULL at that point.

Here is a possible rewriting:

```
void MovieTree::rentMovie(std::string title)
{ 
   MovieNode *foundMovie = root; 
   if (root == NULL) 
   { 
       cout << "Movie not found." << endl;
       return; 
   }

   foundMovie = root; 
   while (foundMovie != NULL) 
   { 
       int compareTitle = foundMovie->title.compare(title); //uses ASCII to determine where titles are 
       if (compareTitle > 0)
       { 
           foundMovie = foundMovie ->leftChild; 
       } 
       else if (compareTitle < 0) //check rightChild 
       { 
           foundMovie = foundMovie->rightChild; 
       }
       else { // compareTitle == 0
           if (foundMovie->quantity > 0) 
           { 
               foundMovie->quantity--;
               cout << "Movie has been rented." << endl;
               //Title entered matches title found 
               cout << "Movie Info:" << endl;
               cout << "===========" << endl; 
               cout << "Ranking:" << foundMovie->ranking << endl; 
               cout << "Title:" << foundMovie->title << endl; 
               cout << "Year:" << foundMovie->year << endl; 
               cout << "Quantity:" << foundMovie->quantity << endl;
               break;
           }
           else if (foundMovie->quantity ==0)
           {
               //If movie is out of stock 
               cout << "Movie out of stock." << endl; 
               break;
           }
        }
    }

    // be sure that foundMovie->title == title is equivalent to foundMovie->title.compare(title) == 0
    if (foundMovie && foundMovie->title == title) 
    {
        cout << "found the movie" << endl; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        cout << "Movie not found." << endl; 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I wasn't sure how else to do this-I appreciate your feedback.